# Does null-coalescence operator match empty string?

Tags: c#, null-coalescing-operator

I have a very simple C# question: aren't the following statements equal when dealing with an empty string?

```
s ?? "default";
```

or

```
(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(s)) ? s : "default";
```

I think: since `string.Empty!=null`, the coalescence operator may set the result of the first statement to an empty value when what I really want is the second. Since string is someway special (== and != are overloaded to value-compare) I just wanted to ask to C# experts to make sure.

Thank you.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, you're right - they're not the same, and in the way that you specified.

If you're not happy with the first form, you could write an extension of:

```
public static string DefaultIfNullOrEmpty(this string x, string defaultValue)
{
    return string.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? defaultValue : x;
}
```

then you can just write:

```
s.DefaultIfNullOrEmpty("default")
```

in your main code.